# How can I export my Comcast address book to my iPad?

Tags: contacts, ipad

I have tried many systems to export my comcast address book to the Ipad without success. The sync worked for my files but not the contacts.  I used carbonites "sync and save" and also tried manually joining the 2 devices.  I am one frustrated old lady.

Comment: Does Comcast allow you to export you contacts in vCard format?  That would be the easiest way to get them into iPad I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide to export your contacts from Comcast in the vCard format (VCF): http://www.watchingthenet.com/export-address-book-contacts-from-comcast-webmail.html

Then, email the vCard file to yourself. Open that email on your iPad and download the attachment. Now you will have your Comcast contacts on your iPad.